# How to pass value from one component to service to fetch in second component in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, service

I am passing a variable data to service to use in second component but in first component when I am creating Service class object in construtor of ts file of fierst component then I am not able to access it in functions of the first component. How to do it so that I can fetch the value in second component

I am getting error in FirstComponent as

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'changeMessage' of undefined
```

## Service Class

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProgressService {

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject('0');
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message)
  }

}
```

## FirstComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProgressService } from 'src/app/services/progress.service';
declare var $:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-initial-setup',
  templateUrl: './initial-setup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./initial-setup.component.css']
})
export class InitialSetupComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private d: ProgressService) { }

  ngOnInit() {


    $('a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {

      //update progress
       var step = $(e.target).data('step');
      var percent = (parseInt( step) / 10) * 100;

      $('.progress-bar').css({width: percent + '%'});
      $('.progress-bar').text("Step" +  step + " of 10");
      //e.relatedTarget // previous tab 


    this.d.changeMessage( step);

    })

  }

}
```

## Second Component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProgressService } from 'src/app/services/progress.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css']
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {

  message:string;


  constructor(public data: ProgressService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you not able to access service in the first component itself?

Comment: yes. it is saying that ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'changeMessage' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Use `ngAfetViewInit` instead of `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import { ProgressService } from 'src/app/services/progress.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css']
})
export class SidebarComponent implements AfterViewInit{

  message:string;

  constructor(public data: ProgressService) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line in the first component is the culprit.
`this.d.changeMessage( step);`

Here you don't have right "this" setup since you are inside a callback.

Change your callback function to arrow function and it should get resolved.

Do this:

from `function (e)` change it to:

`e =>`

Alternatively if you don't mind ugly syntax:
you can add `.bind(this)` when the callback function ends.

like:

```
function (e) {

}.bind(this)
```

Comment: can you tell how to do that

Comment: instead of  function (e) use e =>